# How can I apply custom font on watermark that created by FFmpeg

Tags: android, ffmpeg, custom-font, android-ffmpeg

I am creating a video with FFmpeg library. I want access fonts from Android assets folder and overlay on my video as watermark.

What is the path for Android assets folder to access and apply custom font on FFmpeg?
I can overlay watermark on video but when I try to apply custom font on it, it gives error related to not exist, etc.

#### What I found till now:

The alternative solution that I found is the create an image file and write text on it and overlay image on video. problem is text and image being stretch output. I need a solution for it.

```
String[] execute = {"-y",  "-i",  videoPath, "-i", image, "-filter_complex",
             "[1:v]scale=" + width + ":" + height + "[ovrl],[0:v][ovrl]overlay=(main_w-overlay_w)/2:(main_h-overlay_h)/2"
             ,"-strict" , "experimental", "-vcodec", "libx264" , "-preset",  "ultrafast" , "-crf",  "20", "-acodec",  "aac",  "-ar",
             "44100",  "-ac",  "2",  "-b:v",  "36000k",   outputPath.getPath()};
```

I thought `itz` output will be good but it stretching my text and image.

I want some perfect solution to apply assets font on FFmpeg.

Thank you in Advance.

Comment: can you share you image which you pass a input

Comment: it is transparent image. i have to show some text as well as stickler. so when i capture video at that time i create transparent image and draw text over it later i will show image preview with video and add sticker on it i want to. and if add sticker then i have create another transparent bitmap and draw sticker on it and for result combine those 2 image in one image and use to create video

Comment: from above process my sticker and text stretched.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Assets Directry is nt directly accessible by FFMPEG you have to copy that in internal storage then you can pass t to ffmpeg otherwise ffmpeg troughs error ffmpeg is native library for vdeo editing so it can fetch assets data

You can use `drawtext` attribute to draw text on Image/ Video. Drawtext has its own parameter for fontstyle here is a  simple example code how to draw text on video/image with custom fontstyel and color

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -filter_complex "drawtext=text=Vinesh Chauhan:fontcolor=#000000:fontsize=14:x=43:y=103:fontfile=FACEBOLF.OTF" -y output.mp4
```

here

`text`= what you want to draw as text on video/image

`fontcolor` =  color for font

`fontsize` = fontsize for your text

`x` and `y` is used to draw your text on specified co-ordinates

`fontfile`= pass you fontsyle file(TTF) file path

if you wish to add image as water mark on video do not scale tahat image otherwise it alter the image aspec ratio

use below code that not alter width height of  image

```
String[] execute = {"-y",  "-i",  videoPath, "-i", image, "-filter_complex",
             "[1:v]scale=iw:-2[ovrl],[0:v][ovrl]overlay=(main_w-overlay_w)/2:(main_h-overlay_h)/2"
             ,"-strict" , "experimental", "-vcodec", "libx264" , "-preset",  "ultrafast" , "-crf",  "20", "-acodec",  "aac",  "-ar",
             "44100",  "-ac",  "2",  "-b:v",  "36000k",   outputPath.getPath()};
```

or your app has custom height width functionality so use below code that will maintain your aspect ratio

```
String[] execute = {"-y",  "-i",  videoPath, "-i", image, "-filter_complex",
             "[1:v]scale=" + width + ":-2[ovrl],[0:v][ovrl]overlay=(main_w-overlay_w)/2:(main_h-overlay_h)/2"
             ,"-strict" , "experimental", "-vcodec", "libx264" , "-preset",  "ultrafast" , "-crf",  "20", "-acodec",  "aac",  "-ar",
             "44100",  "-ac",  "2",  "-b:v",  "36000k",   outputPath.getPath()};
```

Comment: I never thought about copy assets folder data to phone directory. this will work for me because i tried system font access into ffmpeg. Let me try.

Comment: can help you to solve your issues mail me if facing any issue

Comment: it will work... just moved to some emergency task. but i believe this will work..

Comment: Surely i will mail you if i got any problem. Thanks

Comment: fabio gurreono ans

Comment: @VineshChauhan Thanks it'z work like charm i have tested and got result. but still i have issue with overlay image that is stretched after getting result  from ffmpeg.

Comment: send me code, input and output on my mail will solve issue